# iOS: Working with custom ui elements

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to use some custom UI elements for an app I'm writing. They're all encased in a .psd in separate layers. Once I isolate them, what's the best way to use them in my app? I've been looking for a tutorial but I can't find anything.

I.e. for a `UIToolbar`, do I add it as a subview?

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(titleToolbar.frame.origin.x,
titleToolbar.frame.origin.y, titleToolbar.frame.size.width,
titleToolbar.frame.size.height)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar1"];
[titleToolbar addSubview:imgView];
```

For a `UIButton`, do I just add it as the background image? Should I be subclassing things?

Forgive my ignorance :(

Comment: You should look into apple's documentation on creating custom view controls.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing what you should do, is subclassing, and make universal components. Then like you did, add from code, and add as subviews.